# How to use REACTJS and Context in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my project, I use a context to translate strings into various Language. In my project, I translate strings with this structure:

```
{Language.La_LAST_PURCHASE_PRICE}
```

Which "Language" refers to context and "La_LAST_PURCHASE_PRICE" is the key to the context that works and does not have any problems.
I have a sales invoice stylesheet that is in HTML format and I save it in the database and put it in a state after running the program and displaying the invoice to the user with the following code.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: this.state.currentStyleTheme}} />
```

In invoice style, I want to write the title with the context to change the language. (Instead of writing the title directly) as follows:

```
{Language.La_INVOICE_TITLE}
```

But in the output of the invoice, it displays {Language.La_INVOICE_TITLE} It does not display the output of the Context and does not work properly.
How to write context or reactJS code between HTML tags stored in database and run in the project? (html is stored in the database with the data type TEXT)

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: this.state.currentStyleTheme}} />
```

`this.state.currentStyleTheme` is treated as a string.

In my opinion, you have 3 choices,

1. use a `String.replace()` method. e.g. `this.state.currentStyleTheme.replace('${Language.La_INVOICE_TITLE}', state.title)`
2. Use server-side rendering so you can manipulate the html element without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
3. use the same structure for each template and dynamic styling from database.

Option 3 might not work if you have a massive difference in the html templates.